# swfobject - flash not showing

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am experiencing some difficulty in having the flash content show on [this page](http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/printing-testimonials.html). I have checked the code and the paths and everything appears to be correct. I have another [page](http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/assets/flash/index.html) in the same directory as the swf file and it works fine so I know that swfobject and the swf file are working properly.

Any ideas why the swf file is not showing properly in the first page?

Thanks!

Comment: When visiting the first page in your post, the firebug error console shows this error message: "$("#imageBarSlides").cycle is not a function". Maybe this prevents the swfobject from working? Firebug is a webdevelopment extension for firefox, see getfirebug.com

Comment: Hi Max. I saw that too. I disabled that rogue "function". The error is now gone, but the swf file still does not show.

Comment: ...and http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/settings.xml is not found whereas in your second link http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/assets/flash/settings.xml is found. I guess settings.xml is data for the swf and that is why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swf file is not in the right directory. The swf is specified as relative to the document you currently on. So your swf should be in this directory:

`http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/expressInstall.swf`

Your settings.xml isn't found. It gives a 404 error.

Try to define a  `<div id="carousel1">` instead of the `<object>`.

Comment: Robert. Thanks to you and Max for your help. I moved the swf file as well as the xml file to the root directory and everything is working properly now. Looks like I need to do some research on paths in swfobject. Thanks again.